# Não consigo eliminar avisos do ESLint

Tags: react, react-native

Estou aprendendo react-native, nunca tive muita experiência com JavaScript, instalei a extensão ESLint e estou tentando seguir a risca buscando a melhor sintaxe.

Porém tem dois avisos que não consegui eliminar e nem consigo entender o porque.

O primeiro sempre que coloco um `alert()` sem importar o conteúdo

```
[eslint] 'alert' is not defined. (no-undef)
function alert(message?: any): void
```

O segundo no require

```
<Image source={require('./imgs/logo.png')} />
```

Também sem importar o conteúdo

```
[eslint] Unexpected require(). (global-require)
function require(name: string): any
```

O app funciona ok mesmo com estes avisos porém gostaria de entendê-los

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Eslint tens um ficheiro de configuração, aí podes dizer ao eslint os ambientes em que trabalhas para ele contar com algumas variáveis globais como o `alert` e `require` [(*****)](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments).

Assim, no ficheiro de configuração `.eslintrc.js` coloca o que precisares:

```
env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true
},
```

***** - <sub>[ver documentação aqui](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)</sub>

Comment: Entendi, porém no meu `.eslintrc.json` tenho apenas isso `{
    "extends": "rallycoding"
}`

Comment: E quando coloco come vc disse apenas marca erros

Comment: @Mateus nesse caso o ficheiro deve ficar assim: `{"extends":"rallycoding","env":{"browser":true,"commonjs":true,"es6":true,"node":true}}`

Comment: Obrigado agora deu certo